# Fetching value from codeigniter form field among input fields of same name

Tags: php, codeigniter

I don't need any code, I just need the right way to do it.

### What I am doing?

Here is the thing. I am making a software for a pharmacy (Drug Store). I have created a tab for shortlist for the drug. See the picture. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STXwX.png)

### What problem I am facing?

In the  last column, I have a form field to input drug or add stock.  But you can see there are many form fields for so many rows. When I click to "Confirm" button, it's not gonna work cause the table has been generated using loop. So, for all the fields there are same name.

How can I take the value of input field right above the submit button. I mean when I click confirm button it will take same row's input field not others.

How can I do it? No code needed. I am using php codeigniter framework.

Thanks

Comment: If you create it via a loop why don't you give unique names to each element via the loop as well?

Comment: There are unique id's already. But I need to take quantity value from input field when click on confirm button. Can you please tell me how can I set and get the exact id when click on confirm button?

Comment: @uzzelsheel you create one variable as tag like '$i' and increase it and append it on last of input name.

Comment: Yes, this will give unique names for different fields. But when I click confirm button I need the value of the field right above the button. Not from the other. How can I do it? As the name of the input fields will be random, I can't mention the name of the field.

Comment: it sounds like you've a big form wrapped around the table - why not creating a form in every cell ?

Comment: I generated form for every cell. But it won't gonna make any difference.

Comment: show your code, otherwise this conversation leads to nothing ;)

Comment: Listen! do 1 thing that put it input name like <input name="name[]"> and it will return whole array of posted value.

Answer (score 0):

create one variable like '$i' and increase it and append it on last of input name.as well as give id to submit button and append id with $i.

for eg. name_1,name_2,submit_2,submit_2

when you submit just get the id of submit button. Then get the number from id eg.2,3.take input from the same input variable id. You can do it using ajax. So it will be done without refresh page.